# php to json with two specific data formats

Tags: php, json

I need to have a JSON from php that looks exactly like this:

```
{
    "nodes": [
                {"x": 250, "y": 250, "color": "grey", "name":"1", "r":"28", "fixed":true},
                {"x": 120, "y": 150, "name":"somename", "score": -12.2, "icon": "someicon"},
                {"x": 140, "y": 150, "name":"someothername", "score": -0.08, "icon": "someothericon"}
            ],
    "links": [
                {"source":  0, "target": 1, "distance": 180},
                {"source":  0, "target": 2, "distance": 180},
                {"source":  0, "target": 2, "distance": 180}
            ]
}
```

The nodes array I get from the db, so what I do afterwards is count how many are, since I have to make a link for each of them (from 1 to n). I've tried doing it like this: (`count($res)` will give me number of nodes I have)

```
$count = count($res);

for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++)
{

    $strings['source'] = 0;
    $strings['target'] = $i;
    $strings['distance'] = 180;

}
```

while defining `$strings = array();` beforehand, but what this counter does is, it'll place only the last value in the array, when in reality, I need `$count` of them, and I need to retain this specific format in order to pass it to JS for further processing.

The contents of `$res` are as follows.

> ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 67 [score] => 0.05 [dscore] => 0.24 [xcord]
>   => 91 [ycord] => 391 [name] => somename [ticker] => tickname [icon] => someicon [datafrom] => 2017-01-01 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 68 [score]
>   => -0.32 [dscore] => 0.55 [xcord] => 120 [ycord] => 428 [name] => othername [ticker] => tickname [icon] => someothericon [datafrom] =>
>   2017-01-01 ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 69 [score] => -0.32 [dscore] =>
>   0.21 [xcord] => 482 [ycord] => 268 [name] => mysanantonio [ticker] => tickname [icon] => some other other icon [datafrom] => 2017-01-01 )

I need to

1. Loop `$i` times and for each of those loops, increase value of
       `target` in `links` by 1
2. Merge the two arrays to get a JSON
       output identical to the one shown at the beggining

Comment: Please show your desired output first. You possibly need to create a 2-d array for `$strings`

Comment: The json that's written first is my desired output. I have the nodes stored in an array that's a direct grab from the database, now I somehow need to include strings in there as well while retaining the format

Comment: Okay, then please `print_r($res)` Need to check what the array looks like.

Comment: Updated the question with more specifics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `$strings` a two dimensional array.

```
$k = 0;
for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++) {

    $strings[$k]['source'] = 0;
    $strings[$k]['target'] = $i;
    $strings[$k]['distance'] = 180;
    $k++;
}   

$strings = array_values( (array)$strings );
echo json_encode($strings);
```

Comment: Using this method will mess up the format in two ways: first, it'll be missing `links` and second, it'll have `"1":` before each line, which the JS on the other end wont accept

Comment: Actually I've managed to merge it all, but the second dimension in the array is making it look bad, since I get `"1":{"source":0,"target":2,"distance":180},"2":{"source":0,"target":3,"distance":180},` instead of `{"source":0,"target":2,"distance":180},{"source":0,"target":3,"distance":180},`
I did `$data['links'] = $strings;` and `$data['nodes'] = $res;` which merges them nicely, but I need to fix those numbers that happen in `$strings`

Comment: That's exactly right, thank you! That made it work perfect